# Firebase firestore .set(data) promise just solve when I signout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to setup a SignUp method for my login component, and it's seems to work fine the first time I use the SignUp method from Firebase. The issue comes up when I signout this newly created user for the first time, and try to create another user with email and password (without refreshing the browser), this one wont be instantly updated in the firebase firestore database, instead the promise will exist but it will only solve to the database when I click my signout method. (If I refresh the browser it works)

This is my SignUp func

```
const signUp = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
FirebaseApp.auth()
  .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then((cred) => {
    console.log('We are inside the .then')
    FirebaseApp.firestore()
      .collection("Users")
      .doc(cred.user.uid)
      .set({
        Name: name,
        LastName: lastname,
        Email: email,
      })
      .then(function () {
        console.log("Stored!");
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }); };
```

I used a console.log inside my first .then to check if I'm indeed going through the success process, and I get the log,
I used a console.log inside my second .then the one who checks data setted to the db.
I get the log,

after that I signout and try to create a second user, but from now on it will only set the data when I signout and not when I use my signup method.

This is my SignOut func

```
<Button
      type="submit"
      fullWidth
      variant="contained"
      color="primary"
      className={classes.submit}
      onClick={() => {
        FirebaseApp.auth().signOut();
      }}
    >
      Sign Out
    </Button>
```

The last thing I tried, was to change the position where I call the .set parallel to the createUserWithEmailAndPassword method with a setTimeout method and it works but is not optimal because if there is a delay during the creation process, the data wont have the user id available to use. or Worst, if the data is being fetch after signup It wont be visible at first.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your case, I would recommend you to change a little bit the way that you are sending the authenticated information to Firestore. Your code should look like this one below.

```
export const signupUser = (userDetails) => {
    const {firstName, lastName, email, password} = userDetails
    return () => {
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(() => {
            firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
            .set({
                firstName: firstName,
                lastName: lastName,
                email: email
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('Something went wrong with added user to firestore: ', error);
            })
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('Something went wrong with sign up: ', error);
        }
    },
};
```

**While this code is untested**, it's based in the one of this very good article here: [How to authenticate a user and create the corresponding document in Cloud Firestore.](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/firebase-authentication-with-firestore-database-78e6e4f348c6)

In addition to the above option, you can try using a Cloud Function, that will be doing the send of information to Firestore, once the user is created.

```
export const newAccountCreated = functions.auth.user().onCreate(user => {
    userDoc = {'email' = user.data.email, 
               'displayName' = user.data.displayName}
    admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(user.data.uid)
    .set(userDoc).then(writeResult => {
        console.log('User Created result:', writeResult);
        return;
    }).catch(err => {
       console.log(err);
       return;
    });
});
```

Using Cloud Funcrion might be an alternative as well, due to the fact that it will be run every time you have an occurrence of user creation.

These two options should help you create the users withing login and help you avoid the issue with needing the logout when trying to create a new one.

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Thanks Gabriel for your support, I tried the first solution, and it kept happening, the same issue. Using Cloud functions seems to be a good Idea, i was just wondering, Do I need a node.js enviorment in order to implement those? it will be my first time using cloud functions from firestore

Comment: Hi @Kadaj Yes, you will need Node.js to deploy Cloud Functions. You can check more information on how to achieve this integration in the official documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions).